# Trying blend/merge column values across multiple rows into a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, blending

I am trying to aggregate some data with pandas such that I create two new columns that store values from an original dataset in an effort to reduce the number of total rows.

For example

```
d = pd.DataFrame([['0001', None, 'backlog', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31'], 
                  ['0001', 'backlog', 'complete', '2020-01-31', '9999-12-31'],
                  ['0001', 'backlog', 'complete', '2020-01-31', '9999-12-31'],
                  ['0002', None, 'backlog', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-25'], 
                  ['0002', None, 'backlog', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-25'],
                  ['0002', None, 'backlog', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-25'],
                  ['0002', None, 'backlog', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-25'],
                  ['0002', 'backlog', 'complete', '2019-02-25', '9999-12-31'],
                  ['0003', None, 'backlog', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31'],
                  ['0003', None, 'backlog', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31'],
                  ['0003', None, 'backlog', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-31'],
                  ['0003', 'backlog', 'modified', '2020-01-31', '2020-02-05'],
                  ['0003', 'modified', 'qe_backlog', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-20'],
                  ['0003', 'qe_backlog', 'verified', '2020-02-20', '9999-12-31']] ,
                 columns=['id', 'old_state', 'new_state', 'start_dttm', 'end_dttm'])
```

results in

```
      id   old_state   new_state  start_dttm    end_dttm
0   0001        None     backlog  2020-01-15  2020-01-31
1   0001     backlog    complete  2020-01-31  9999-12-31
2   0001     backlog    complete  2020-01-31  9999-12-31
3   0002        None     backlog  2019-02-15  2019-02-25
4   0002        None     backlog  2019-02-15  2019-02-25
5   0002        None     backlog  2019-02-15  2019-02-25
6   0002        None     backlog  2019-02-15  2019-02-25
7   0002     backlog    complete  2019-02-25  9999-12-31
8   0003        None     backlog  2020-01-15  2020-01-31
9   0003        None     backlog  2020-01-15  2020-01-31
10  0003        None     backlog  2020-01-15  2020-01-31
11  0003     backlog    modified  2020-01-31  2020-02-05
12  0003    modified  qe_backlog  2020-02-05  2020-02-20
13  0003  qe_backlog    verified  2020-02-20  9999-12-31
```

In the end what I would like is:

```
id   state       backlog_dttm      completed_dttm  modified_dttm qe_backlog_dttm    verified_dttm
0001 complete     2020-01-15       2020-01-31           null            null       null 
0002 complete     2019-02-15       2019-02-25      null        null     null      null
0003 verified     2020-01-15       null            2020-01-31        2020-02-05        2020-02-20
```

So far I have

```
d.drop_duplicates(subset=d.columns, keep='last', inplace=True)
d.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Then at this point, trying to set backlog_dttm, things stop working.

```
d2['backlog_dttm'] = d[d['old_state'].isnull() & (d['new_state'] == 'backlog')]['start_dttm']
d2 = d.loc[d['end_dttm'] == d.end_dttm.max()]
d2.loc[d2.index,'backlog_dttm'] = d[d['old_state'].isnull() & (d['new_state'] == 'backlog')]['start_dttm']
d2.loc[d2.index, 'completed_dttm'] = d[d['new_state'] == 'complete']['start_dttm']
d2.loc[d2.index, 'modified_dttm'] = d[d['new_state'] == 'modified']['start_dttm']
d2.loc[d2.index, 'qe_backlog_dttm'] = d[d['new_state'] == 'qe_backlog']['start_dttm']
```

The above results in a SettingWithCopyWarning, but appears to work. The final desired output should look similar to this:

```
       old_state new_state  start_dttm    end_dttm backlog_dttm  \
id                                                                
0001     backlog  complete  2020-01-31  9999-12-31   2020-01-15   
0002     backlog  complete  2019-02-25  9999-12-31   2019-02-15   
0003  qe_backlog  verified  2020-02-20  9999-12-31   2020-01-15   

     completed_dttm modified_dttm qe_backlog_dttm  
id                                                 
0001     2020-01-31           NaN             NaN  
0002     2019-02-25           NaN             NaN  
0003            NaN    2020-01-31      2020-02-05
```

As an FYI: this is only a sample, the real dataset is based on a development workflow where there would be other states like ready_to_test, verified, in_progress, etc... and likewise there would be columns I need to populate for these states as well, i.e. verified_dttm, read_to_test_dttm..

The start_dttm and end_dttm fields are used to identify the date a record entered a given state and the date it left that state.

Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.  -Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
# find the most recent state for each id
df1 = df.groupby('id').agg({'new_state':'last'})
# find start dates for each new state by id and unstack into columns
df2 = df.groupby(['id','new_state'])['start_dttm'].agg('first').unstack()
# merge grouped dataframes together by id
df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df)                                                                                                        
     id new_state     backlog    complete    modified  qe_backlog    verified
0  0001  complete  2020-01-15  2020-01-31         NaN         NaN         NaN
1  0002  complete  2019-02-15  2019-02-25         NaN         NaN         NaN
2  0003  verified  2020-01-15         NaN  2020-01-31  2020-02-05  2020-02-20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of the SettingWithCopyWarning you could specifying the index when adding a column

```
d2.loc[d2.index,'backlog_dttm'] = d[d['old_state'].isnull() & (d['new_state'] == 'backlog')]['start_dttm']
```

Kenan's hack solution seems to work well of just renaming the columns besides that.

Answer (score 0):

If `old_state` in `[None, backlog]` and `new_state` in `[backlog, completed]`

You can hack a solution with

```
df[df['old_state'].isna()].assign(old_state='complete').drop('new_state', axis=1).rename(columns={'old_state': 'state', 'start_dttm': 'backlog_dttm', 'end_dttm': 'completed_dttm'})
```

```
     id     state backlog_dttm completed_dttm
0  0001  complete   2020-01-15     2020-01-31
2  0002  complete   2019-02-15     2019-02-25
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try; however, my one concern is that this is only a sample data set.  The actual data set has over 20 columns so this approach might be prone to typos.  There are also far more states than those that I mentioned.  This is data from a development engineering workflow so there are additional states like `read to test`, `verified`,  where I would also have a column called ready_for_test_dttm and verified_dttm.

Comment: Yeah I thought I had a good sample until I realized I didn't.

Comment: Done, i believe I have a more accurate representation of the data.